# How to detect if a user has gone past certain locational boundaries physically

Tags: bluetooth, gps, software, board

I want to write some software that takes the location of a user's phone and makes sure it is within a certain boundary that is set by "invisible fences"; see the picture below.

What kind of circuitry, or board or chip can I put on these posts to draw that "fence" so called?

The red circles are the posts, and the red lines are the "fence". What's in the middle is like a stadium.

[image]

Comment: The term you are looking for it "[geofencing](https://developers.google.com/location-context/geofencing)". There are already apps for that.

Comment: yeah your phone already has GPS and the ability to run software. The kind of circuitry you need is "none".

Comment: Step 1) Assume the user is carrying their phone...

Comment: Carrying probably a smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with Bluetooth, if you take the signalstrength (dBm) as a distance measurement. If you use an app like nRF connect you can see all visible bluetooth devices around you.

The issue is, because of privacy smartphones hide their radio's because of these actions.. But maybe you just use some BT device.

If you have at least 3 measurements of those poles, you can measure by triangulation. If you have three points on a map and you know where they are located, you imaginably draw a circle around each point with a radius of the known distance to the object and at the intersection of those circles is the object.

Of course there is a margin.

Comment: why would you do triangulation when the phone has, built-in, a system for localization based on the time-difference of arrival?

Comment: (that system by the way is GPS/Beidou/Galileo/GLONASS)

Comment: Yes ok, I wrongly understood that the object/phone was passive. But when active yes better. At least: if the poles are out of each other far enough.

Comment: no, GPS is a passive system - it only receives.

Comment: I know, I mean like you don't have access to the phone. Like if you want to know is somebody is entering the area between the poles.